# how to merge two sublists sharing any number in common?(2)

Tags: python, list, sublist

Given that:

```
list=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11]]
```

I have asked a similar question before, I have tried the code on
[how to merge two sublists sharing any number in common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825639/how-to-merge-two-sublists-sharing-any-number-in-common)
but I am stuck in my code now.
I want to merge the sublists that share a common number,
e.g. `[1,2,3]` and `[3,4,5]` can merge to give [`1,2,3,4,5]` as they share a common number, `3`.
In `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6]],` although `[1,2,3] and [3,4,5]` share a common number, `3`,
`[3,4,5]` and `[5,6]` also share a common number, `5`, so I want all three of them to merge then gives
`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

So for list,
my expected result is:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[9,10,11]]
```

I have tried the following code but don't know what is wrong, can anyone help?

```
    s = map(set, list)
    for i, si in enumerate(s):
        for j, sj in enumerate(s):
            if i != j and si & sj:
                s[i] = si | sj
                s[j] = set()
    list=[list(el) for el in s if el]
    print list
>>>[[5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11]]
```

Comment: What is the expected output of `[[1,3],[1,2],[3,4]]`? The first sublist shares elements with both the second and third sublist, which should be merged?

Comment: @Cyber:
sorry for being confusing, 
`[[1,3],[1,2],[3,4]]` should give `[1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Be wary of assigning names like `list` as this will override the built-in `list` type.

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge_containing(input_list):
    merged_list = [set(input_list[0])]
    i = 0
    for sub_list in input_list:
        if not set(sub_list).intersection(set(merged_list[i])):  # 1
            merged_list.append(set())  # 2
            i += 1  # 2
        merged_list[i].update(set(sub_list))  # 3

    return [sorted(sub_list) for sub_list in merged_list]  # 4

mylist=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11]]
print merge_containing(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11]]
```

How does it work:

1. Check if the sub_list set shares any common member with the current
   index set of the merged_list.
2. If it **doesn't**, add a new empty set to the merged_list and increment
   the index.
3. Adds the sub_list set to the set at index in the merged_list.
4. Converts from set to list and return

Comment: This works for the example, but consider one more complicated like: `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51]]`

Comment: What should it return?

Comment: This, I think? [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14], [51], [65], [140], [231]]

Comment: Well, the question doesn't make that clear. It states that to make a common list current list must share at least one common number in the next list, thus `[1,2,3],[3,4,5]` becomes `[1,2,3,4,5]` because they share the number `3`. But it doesn't states that the numbers within the list must have a interval of 1, thus `[1,2,4]` becoming `[1,2],[4]`. Anyway, I see that you found the answer yourself, if you feel that it's needed to updated my answer I would gladly do it.

Comment: You're right. I made that assumption. There seem to be different ways of interpreting the intention of the OP. I may alter my answer later to reflect this; however... I apologize if it seems like I'm on your case, but the OP confirmed earlier that this: [[1,3],[1,2],[3,4]] should result in [1,2,3,4]. While your algorithm does this properly, it does not handle the following: [[3,4], [1,2], [1,3]], instead giving the result `[[3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]. I see we both still have work to do... ;) (Edited: mixed up two lists)

Comment: @Eithos:
sorry for the late reply, `[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51]`
should return [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[9,10,11],[65,231,140]]

Comment: @f.rodrigues:
sorry for the late reply, [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51] should return [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[9,10,11],[65,231,140]]
No one has given me the right answer yet, sorry for making a mistake

Comment: @Na Lai: Plenty of people have given you an answer that works for your problem. It's not clear what more you're looking for. I misinterpreted your question at first, but my other answer (more like jonrsharpe's solution), does exactly what you've asked. ***Unless*** what you're looking for (based on your example here: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[9,10,11],[65,231,140]]) is a solution that also does not sort the resulting numbers: this `[65,231,140]` instead of `[65,140,231]`. The problem with this is that it wouldn't be clear when to sort;i.e should it be sorted only if it's been joined to another list

Comment: ... so that any isolated lists go unsorted? Finally, if this isn't it either: you should explain what else you're looking for, if it's further explanations on how the algorithms work, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def merge(list_of_lists):
        number_set = set()
        for l in list_of_lists:
            for item in l:
                number_set.add(item)    
        return sorted(number_set)  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11]]
        merged = merge(list_of_lists)
        print merged
```

Comment: This only flattens the list. It doesn't group them into new sequences the way the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This solution may be difficult to grasp at first, but it's quite logical and succint, IMO.

The list comprehension basically has two layers. The outer layer will itself create separate lists
for each value of `i` (outer index) that satisfies the condition that the value it points to in the list is not equal to the value pointed to by the previous index + 1. So every numerical jump greater than one will create a new list within the outer list comprehension.

The math around the second (inner list comprehension) condition is a bit more complicated to explain, but essentially the condition seeks to make sure that the inner list only begins counting from the point where the outer index is at, stopping to where once again there is a numerical jump greater than one.

Assuming an even *more* complicated input:

```
listVar=[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51]]

# Flattens the lists into one sorted list with no duplicates.
l = sorted(set([x for b in listVar for x in b]))

lGen = xrange(len(l))

print [
    [l[i2] for i2 in lGen if l[i2] + i == l[i] + i2] 
    for i in lGen if l[i] != l[i-1] + 1
]

>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14], [51], [65], [140], [231]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as a new answer since the OP already accepted my other.

But as pointed out by @Eithos,

the input:

```
[[3,4], [1,2], [1,3]]
```

should return

```
[[1,2,3,4]]
```

and the input

```
[[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51]]
```

should return

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14], [51], [65], [140], [231]]
```

Here's my attempt:

```
from itertools import chain

def merge_containing(input_list):
    print " input:", input_list
    chain_list = sorted(set(chain(*input_list))) # 1
    print " chain:",chain_list
    return_list = []
    new_sub_list = []
    for i, num in enumerate(chain_list):
        try:
            if chain_list[i + 1] == chain_list[i] + 1:  # 2
                new_sub_list.append(num)
            else:
                new_sub_list.append(num)  # 3
                return_list.append(new_sub_list)
                new_sub_list = []
        except IndexError:
            new_sub_list.append(num)  # 3
            return_list.append(new_sub_list)

    print 'result:', return_list
    return return_list

mylist = [[3,4], [1,2], [1,3]]
merge_containing(mylist)
print
mylist = [[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6],[6,7],[9,10],[10,11],[65,231,140], [13,14,51]]
merge_containing(mylist)
```

Output:

```
 input: [[3, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
 chain: [1, 2, 3, 4]
result: [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

 input: [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [9, 10], [10, 11], [65, 231, 140], [13, 14, 51]]
 chain: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 51, 65, 140, 231]
result: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11], [13, 14], [51], [65], [140], [231]]
```

Explanation:

This one is a little hacky them the last one

1. I use itertool.chain to flat all the lists and them I sort it.
2. Then I check if the current number is within the range of 1 digit from the next
3. If it is I store it in the new_sub_list, if not I store in the new_sub_list, then store new_sub_list in the return_list, and empty the new_sub_list.

Note the `try/except Index Error`, it to avoid comparing the last item of the list with one that doesn't exist,

Answer (score 0):

Well... I couldn't resist answering @f.rodrigues' last answer with one of my own.

I have to be honest though, this final version was heavily influenced by jonrsharpe's solution (the code went through various revisions, each one more efficient until I realized his method was the only way to press the most amount of juice) over here: [Using sublists to create new lists where numbers don't repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802820/using-sublists-to-create-new-lists-where-numbers-dont-repeat)

Which made me wonder... why are we answering the same question over and over again (from the very same person)? ***This*** question, [how to merge two sublists sharing any number in common?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825639/how-to-merge-two-sublists-sharing-any-number-in-common) ***and*** the one with jonrsharpe's solution.

Anyway, this joins lists in the way outlined in his first question, but, like the solutions he already received over there, this one also works just as well for solving this problem.

```
sequence = [[1, 4, 9], [2, 3, 6], [4, 13, 50], [13, 23, 29], [2, 3, 7]]

def combineSequences(seq):

    for index, y in enumerate(seq):
        while True:
            for x in seq[index + 1:]:
                if any(i in x for i in seq[index]):
                    seq.remove(x)
                    y.extend(x)
                    break
            else:
                index += 1
                break

    return [sorted(set(l)) for l in seq]

sequence = [[1, 4, 9], [2, 3, 6], [4, 13, 50], [13, 23, 29], [2, 3, 7]]
print combineSequences(sequence)

>>> [[1, 4, 9, 13, 23, 29, 50], [2, 3, 6, 7]] 

sequence = [[3, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
print combineSequences(sequence)

>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

This solution operates under a different assumption than the one I made earlier, just to clarify. This simply joins lists that have a common number. If the idea, however, was to only have them separated by intervals of 1, see my other answer.

That's it!