# Given lists of related numbers, merge related lists to create disjoint sets

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Given:

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(3,7),(5,7)]
```

Output:

```
[set(1,2), set(3,4,5,6,7)]
```

Explanation:

```
(1,2)
(1,2), (3,4)
(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)
(1,2), (3,4,7), (5,6)
(1,2), (3,4,7,5,6)
```

I have written a lousy algorithm:

```
Case 1: both numbers in pair are new (never seen before):
    Make a new set with these two numbers
Case 2: one of the number in pair is new, other is already a part of some set:
    Merge the new number in other's set
Case 3: both the numbers belong to some set:
    Union the second set into first. Destroy the second set.
```

Is there a more pythonic (fancy) solution to this algo?

Comment: Do you mean like http://stackoverflow.com/q/27802820/3001761?

Comment: @jonrsharpe code given in your link has O(n^2) complexity. If limited numbers are there and using dict is allowed, it can be done in single iteration.

Comment: Ok, so write that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Unionfind algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this. First, we are using a dictionary to create a tree from the pairs:

```
leaders = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

Now we use two functions -- `union` and `find` -- to populate that tree:

```
def find(x):
    l = leaders[x]
    if l is not None:
        l = find(l)
        leaders[x] = l
        return l
    return x

def union(x, y):
    lx, ly = find(x), find(y)
    if lx != ly:
        leaders[lx] = ly
```

Just iterate over all the pairs and put them into the tree.

```
for a, b in [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(3,7),(5,7)]:
    union(a, b)
```

It then looks like this: `{1: 2, 2: None, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: None}`

[image]

Finally, we group the numbers by their respective "leaders", i.e. what is returned by `find`:

```
groups = collections.defaultdict(set)
for x in leaders:
    groups[find(x)].add(x)
```

Now, `groups.values()` is `[set([1, 2]), set([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]`

Complexity should be something on the order of *O(nlogn)*.