# Create unique ids for a group

Tags: python

I am working on a problem where I have to group related items and assign a unique id to them. I have written the code in python but it is not returning the expected output. I need assistance in refining my logic. The code is below:

```
data = {}
child_list = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    parent = row['source']
    child = row['target']
    #print 'Parent: ', parent
    #print 'Child:', child
    child_list.append(child)
    #print child_list
    if parent not in data.keys():
        data[parent] = []
    if parent != child:
        data[parent].append(child)
    #print data

op = {}
gid = 0


def recursive(op,x,gid):
    if x in data.keys() and data[x] != []:
        for x_child in data[x]:
            if x_child in data.keys():
                op[x_child] = gid
                recursive(op,x_child,gid)
            else:
                op[x] = gid
    else:
        op[x] = gid


for key in data.keys():
    #print "Key: ", key
    if key not in child_list:
        gid = gid + 1
        op[key] = gid
        for x in data[key]:
            op[x] = gid
            recursive(op,x,gid)

related = pd.DataFrame({'items':op.keys(),
                  'uniq_group_id': op.values()})
mapped.sort_values('items')
```

Example below

```
Input:
source  target
a        b
b        c
c        c
c        d
d        d
e        f
a        d
h        a
i        f  

Desired Output:
item     uniq_group_id
a         1 
b         1
c         1
d         1
h         1
e         2
f         2
i         2
```

My code gave me below output which is wrong.

```
item    uniq_group_id
a       3
b       3
c       3
d       3
e       1
f       2
h       3
i       2
```

Another Example

```
Input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['a','b','c','c','d','e','a','h','i','a'],
                'target':['b','c','c','d','d','f','d','a','f','a']})
Desired Output:
item    uniq_group_id
a       1
b       1
c       1
d       1
e       2
f       2

My code Output:
item    uniq_group_id
e   1
f   1
```

The order of the rows or the group id does not matter. The important thing here is to assign related items a same unique identifier. The whole problem is to find related group of items and assign them a unique group id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't analyzed your code closely, but it looks like the error is because of the way you populate the `data` dictionary. It stores a child node as being a neighbor of its parent node, but it also needs to store the parent as being a neighbor of the child.

Rather than attempting to fix your code I decided to adapt [this pseudocode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21078752/4014959) written by Aseem Goyal. The code below takes its input data from simple Python lists, but it should be easy to adapt it to work with a Pandas dataframe.

```
''' Find all the connected components of an undirected graph '''

from collections import defaultdict

src = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'h', 'i', 'a']
tgt = ['b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'a']

nodes = sorted(set(src + tgt))
print('Nodes', nodes)

neighbors = defaultdict(set)
for u, v in zip(src, tgt):
    neighbors[u].add(v)
    neighbors[v].add(u)

print('Neighbors')
for n in nodes:
    print(n, neighbors[n])

visited = {}
def depth_first_traverse(node, group_id):
    for n in neighbors[node]:
        if n not in visited:
            visited[n] = group_id
            depth_first_traverse(n, group_id)

print('Groups')
group_id = 1
for n in nodes:
    if n not in visited:
        visited[n] = group_id
        depth_first_traverse(n, group_id)
        group_id += 1
    print(n, visited[n])
```

**output**

```
Nodes ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'h', 'i']
Neighbors
a {'a', 'd', 'b', 'h'}
b {'a', 'c'}
c {'d', 'b', 'c'}
d {'d', 'a', 'c'}
e {'f'}
f {'i', 'e'}
h {'a'}
i {'f'}
Groups
a 1
b 1
c 1
d 1
e 2
f 2
h 1
i 2
```

This code was written for Python 3, but will also run on Python 2. If you do run it on Python 2 you should add `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your import statements; it's not strictly necessary, but it will make the output look nicer.

Comment: Thank you. This logic is working fine for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Union-Find, or Disjoint-Sets algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for this. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850318/1639625) for a more complete explanation. Basically, you need two functions, `union` and `find`, to create a tree (i.e. a nested dictionary) of `leaders` or predecessors:

```
leaders = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)

def find(x):
    l = leaders[x]
    if l is not None:
        l = find(l)
        leaders[x] = l
        return l
    return x

def union(x, y):
    lx, ly = find(x), find(y)
    if lx != ly:
        leaders[lx] = ly
```

You can apply this to your problem as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['a','b','c','c','d','e','a','h','i','a'],
                   'target': ['b','c','c','d','d','f','d','a','f','a']})

# build the tree
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    union(row["source"], row["target"])

# build groups based on leaders
groups = collections.defaultdict(set)
for x in leaders:
    groups[find(x)].add(x)
for num, group in enumerate(groups.values(), start=1):
    print(num, group)
```

Result:

```
1 {'e', 'f', 'i'}
2 {'h', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b'}
```